# How do I run Flutter in multiple iOS Simulators

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Environment:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.19.0-2.0.pre.214, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-PH)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

When I run `flutter devices` all I get are the following:

```
Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61
<and my physical devices which I ommited>
```

Now when I run `flutter emulators`, I get the built-in **apple_ios_simulator** and the Android emulator which I created:

```
apple_ios_simulator • iOS Simulator • Apple  • ios
Pixel_API_R         • Pixel API R   • Google • android
```

Creating an Android emulator is easy, I can just add as much AVDs I want using Android studio and they'll show up every time I call `flutter emulators`.

How do I do that for iOS simulators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, apparently iOS Simulators are not regarded as `flutter emulators`. For the life of me, I could not find any documentation regarding this so here it goes.

The iOS Simulator can be run with `flutter emulators --launch apple_ios_simulator`

After launching this when you run `flutter devices` it will appear as a device.

```
3 connected devices:

iPhone 11                  • DCDA3304-2E80-4BCD-B0D5-968C2EBD2FA3 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)
Web Server                 • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome                     • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61
```

Then just run another simulator via the Simulator app

[image]

Run `flutter devices` once again to check if another iOS Simulator device has showed up

```
4 connected devices:

iPhone 11                  • DCDA3304-2E80-4BCD-B0D5-968C2EBD2FA3 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)
iPhone SE (2nd generation) • 59D9A787-E68B-4CE1-8CDB-2A5D3CBF0093 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)
Web Server                 • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
Chrome                     • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61
```

And from there you can just run `flutter run -d all`.

Comment: Is there a way to run two indenpendent instances of iOS Simulator at the same time? Each instance is a completely different Flutter app.

Comment: You can run many iOS Simulators @SonXuanNguyen same concept too just specify which device you will use when you run the application on

Comment: @ZonilyJame is this still working same in flutter 2.10.X version. After upgrading to the 2.10.X version of flutter. I am unable to see the iOS Simulator device/physical devices. Can you check and let me know what to do?